# Windows 8.1 StreamSocketListener c#

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

So I'm fairly new to programming and decided to try some networking but I'm stuck.  I tried to create a simple client and server just to establish a connection.  Obviously, it doesnt work, and I've looked around but can't find any **new** information to help me.  So I decided to try here.

Here is what's happening when I run the client and server:

(I'm running the client and server on the same computer)

*Client connects to server (localhost):

-System.Exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

*Client connects to server when server is not running:

-System.Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

*Client connects to localhost at port 80 (which is not the server):

-Connection established

*Client connect to HostName google.com at port 80:

-Connection established

*Client connects to random ip and port:

-System.Exception: No such host is known.

Servercode:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    StreamSocketListener _listener = new StreamSocketListener();
    string port = "1800";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        listener();
    }
    private async void listener()
    {
        _listener.ConnectionReceived += listenerConnectionReceived;
        await _listener.BindServiceNameAsync(port);
    }
    void listenerConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        tb_server.Text = "Connection received.";
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Clientcode:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    StreamSocketListener _listener = new StreamSocketListener();
    string port = "1800";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        listener();
    }
    private async void listener()
    {
        _listener.ConnectionReceived += listenerConnectionReceived;
        await _listener.BindServiceNameAsync(port);
    }
    void listenerConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        tb_server.Text = "Connection received.";
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [StreamSocket](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket) sample.

When debugging an app, Visual Studio automatically creates a [loopback exemption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx) to test a connection from a WinRT client (`StreamSocket`) to a local server.

The exemption does not work the other way, from a local client to a WinRT server (`StreamSocketListener`). You will need to run the server in a different machine.

Also, if you are using `SreamSocketListener` you need the [`internetClientServer` capability](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/StreamSocket/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L52).

If your server is running in another machine in the local network, you need the [`privateNetworkClientServer` capability](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/StreamSocket/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L53).

Comment: Thank you, I "fixed" it by putting both seperate apps (Server & Client) into a single one and that solved it.